# How do I configure TeamCity build agents to use git and the git:// protocol over a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: git, github, ssh, teamcity, socks

I'm trying to setup our TeamCity build agent in a production datacenter with a stricter network. How do I configure the build agents to use git (client-side checkouts) over a SOCKS proxy? TeamCity (as of 6.5) doesn't support authenticated https protocol to github.com so my only option is to make Default Private Key authentication over the git protocol working.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the private key in /.ssh/config (where  is on the build server and is the home directory for the user running the Team City agent) is registered with your project on github (this is the key that will be used as a result of choosing the *Default Private Key* setting)?

You should set up N key pairs, all registered in github against your project, where N is the number of build servers you're using (running multiple agents on a single machine under the same user will be fine as they'll all use the same key).

I'd first suggest you log in to the build server itself and try
`ssh -T git@github.com` (as suggested in "Test Everything Out" in [github's ssh help](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)).  If that works then you should be good to go.  If not then use `ssh -vT git@github.com` to get some verbose output and investigate...